# index match for multiple criterias and using wildcards

Tags: excel, indexing, match, wildcard

I'm trying to do an Index-Match using wildcards and I can't seem to find any solution on the net that can help with my situation.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/fvekv.png

Based on the above, I'm trying to match the three most right columns with the three most left columns to return the value in the 4th column from the left (eg. "BOB") into the column to the right of the rightmost in my image.

This has been the formula that I have been working with (using ctrl+shift+enter):

> =INDEX($H$2:$H$19,MATCH(1,(K2=$E$2:$E$19)*(L2=$F$2:$F$19)*(M2=$G$2:$G$19),0))

where K, L, M are the 3 right most columns and E, F, G are the arrays in the left 3 columns, and column H is where the text sits eg. "BOB"

Could you advise what is the best way to go about it?

Currently if the right columns has a line 129,0102,0000 it won't pick up as a match to the left 129,01*,0000.

Edit: I think I've boiled down the issue to:

> 1. MATCH can't be using exact matches to match wildcards
> 2. If using approximate matches i.e. 1/-1, then the formula is unable to function as intended, picking matches that aren't matches

Comment: I can't see word `TAX` anywhere in the posted snapshot. What is a matching example in the posted snapshot?

Comment: sorry, updated the above

Comment: What is matching result in posted snapshot?

Comment: It just returns an error. The wildcard matching component i.e. k2=e2:e19 isn't working